# django-elasticsearch-dsl suggest not working

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I have created the following document using django-elasticsearch-dsl.

```
@registry.register_document
class QuestionDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        name = 'questions'

    class Django:
        model = QuestionModel
        fields = ['title', 'text']
```

Now when i try to do a suggest with below command

```
QuestionDocument.search().suggest("questions", "text", completion={'field': 'title'}).to_queryset().all()
```

I get the following error:

```
 elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Field [title] is not a completion suggest field')
```

What am i doing wrong here? and how can i fix it? I tried to find a tutorial in the package documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `Field [title] is not a completion suggest field` implies that your `title` field is not of type `completion` which is required in order to use it in a suggest query. Can you show your mapping ?

Comment: For Django model fields, django-elasticsearch-dsl automatically creates mappings to elasticsearch, but i don't know how to create a new mapping on elasticsearch using django-elasticsearch-dsl.

Answer (score 2):

`Field [title] is not a completion suggest field` implies that your title field is not of type `completion` which is required in order to use it in a suggest query.

You need to define your `QuestionDocument` class like this instead:

```
@registry.register_document
class QuestionDocument(Document):

    title = fields.CompletionField()             <--- add this

    class Index:
        name = 'questions'

    class Django:
        model = QuestionModel
        fields = ['text']                        <--- remove title here
```

Comment: This returns error saying that the field cannot be redeclared. The exact error message: `django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.RedeclaredFieldError: You cannot redeclare the field named 'title' on QuestionDocument`

Comment: Fixed, of course, you also need to remove it from the fields declaration in the `Django` class

Comment: This still gives error, saying that title is not a Completion suggest field. `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Field [title] is not a completion suggest field')
`

Comment: Yes, you probably need to delete your index and let Django recreate it with the new field definition

Comment: I deleted the indexes too, still not working but i assume this should work. Think i just wont use django_elasticsearch_dsl, sucks anyway. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 2 days passed and is still haven't found a proper solution to this problem. This is getting very frustating

Comment: There is no time guarantee over here, people are helping in best effort mode ;-)